# Raycasting precision

Tags: unity-game-engine

Some background: My camera is set to a position of 5 in the y axis and -10 in the z axis with a rotation of 22.5.

Does the position and rotation of the camera affect how accurate the raycasting behaviour will be? I ask because there are clickable objects in my scene which detect if they've been clicked on, and it more or less works. I mean it *works*, but it's not perfect.

If I click somewhere on the object, it's likely to register the click, but if I go to test the boundaries, something interesting occurs. There is an area of several pixels under the object which registers a click even though it isn't physically a part of the object. Likewise, there is an area of several pixels on the top of the object (within the object) which does not register a click even though it is a part of the object. Does this have something to do with the angle formed by the ray between the camera and the screen point? My project is more or less bare, so I'm pretty certain that the issue must be caused by the camera's transform and my click script which is really simple at the moment.

```c#
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.transform == gameObject.transform)
            {
                Debug.Log(gameObject.name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should be very accurate, [docs say](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenPointToRay.html) ray goes from camera-near-plane through the screen point. Maybe your BoxCollider is off a bit?

Comment: What kinf of object is it? If it's not a primitiv maybe the MeshCollider is not accurate?

Comment: @derHugo It is a primitive sphere scaled down to 0.25 0.25 0.25

Comment: @KYL3R It's a sphere collider, and it looks normal. Hmmm

Comment: Use [Debug.DrawRay](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawRay.html) to view the actual ray (only visible in scene) and click the object with the sphere collider, to see the actual bounds.

Comment: @KYL3R The rays don't actually go to the spheres. They go to a screen point. This is visible in the 2D view.

Comment: It should *start* on the screen. Okay, a ray is probably not suitable for debugging. Use [DrawLine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Debug.DrawLine.html) and use parameters start = ray.origin & end = hit.point. Now look where it actually stops. It must stop on a collider. Inspect all colliders in scene view to find the one you are hitting, and see if that helps. Report back with a screenshot otherwise :)